# Is there a nice guide to making android apps by hand with just a text editor (e.g. no eclipse ide)?

Tags: android

I want to create apps manually. Using eclipse is the easy way. Using just a text editor is the hard way, but ensure I will know exactly what I'm doing, which is how I like to work.

Are there any good tutorials out there?

**EDIT 3:31pm 10/17/2011:** I realized what my question should have really been after googling around: Are there any good resources that describe the directory contents of an Android project in detail? The idea here is to be able to create them manually.

Comment: Ouch I couldn't imagine defining xml layouts in notepad. At least eclipse formats and detects errors. After developing with Android (in Eclipse) about a month, I learned exactly what was going on (and how mostly everything worked). All you are doing by programming in notepad is straining your pinky from all the "tabbing" :). But hey, to each their own.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea...
What about automatically generated classes, like R.java?  What about viewing your XML layouts after writing them to double check that they are correct?  If you want to create apps "manually" because you don't like tabs (or you have some other formatting issue), then you can set up Eclipse to format the way you like.  There's no reason to not use an IDE, and there's a reason why Google suggests in their tutorials to use Eclipse.

Comment: I really think you should rethink your approach to "really learning" Android development. In all honesty, Eclipse doesn't really hide much from you in the way of development. It mostly just helps simplifies tasks that would otherwise be extremely repetitive in a normal text editor.

Comment: Well, I use Notepad++, which isn't just a text editor, but at the same time isn't an IDE. I can use Notepad++ for simple things like validating my XML documents, and inserting XML tags rapidly (e.g. typing a word then pressing tab to make it into an element). I've edited my question to be better suited to what I'm looking for, check it out.

Comment: Start with Eclipse. You'll learn the more important part of the development such as the code, classes, standards etc. Once you have those down consider branching out to Notepad++, UltraEdit, or the like. There's no point biting off more than you can chew (which you ARE doing here)

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll do what I hate doing: install an IDE... But I'm going to uninstall it as soon as I can! I hate IDEs, but if that's the most definitive way to learn the directory structure and rules of an Android project, then I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google tells you all about how to manage things from the command line [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html). Pretty straight forward.

That said, I think I'd have to recommend against going low level here. I used emacs and ant for several months while learning/tinkering with android programming, but it wasn't really that helpful. The whole android system seems designed for use in an IDE: use of XML for layout, automatically generated values in `R.java`, a big API with many similar sounding names (layouts vs views, `OnTouchListener` vs `OnClickListener`), etc. I can't say I really started to get the big picture of the system until I could see it all organized for me. I'm still on the command line for a lot of C/C++, and even some Java stuff too, but all it did for android was cause frustration.

**EDIT**

Just saw your edit for the directory structure. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just have to do it with eclipse until I learn it well enough to do on my own.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like Android development was intended for an IDE.  I personally don't like that. For example, in web development, I hate using Dreamweaver. I think there can be an easier way to do all of this Android development. Maybe there'll be someone to change it all up sometime.

Answer (score 1):

If you must...

First install ant, then assuming sdk/tools is in your $PATH:

`android create-project -n projectname -t android-13 -k here.namespace.your -a MyActivity -p projectname`

Where android-13 is an installed platform, run `android list targets` to see which platforms you have. Then run `ant release` or `ant debug` to build, or just `ant` to get a list of possible targets. When you're ready to test, run `ant install` to install it onto a running emulator or attached device.

See [Tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/) in the dev guide.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the $PATH variable on these school computers.

Comment: That's odd, you should be able to alter the environment of any process you own. Doing so isn't a security risk and not really preventable if they allow you to run your own programs. In any case you can still prefix "android" with the path to the tools directory.

Comment: Well I noticed that Android SDK installs for the local user much like Google Chrome does. I really can't edit the $PATH variable, I tried!

Comment: But indeed, that's not to big of a deal. I can make a .lnk or .bat file to make things almost identical on the command line (e.g. using "android.lnk" instead of just "android".

Answer (score 0):

Intel xdk. Do the whole app in html, css, php, and javascript.  Inel xdk can build it in different platforms.(android, iphone, and windows.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

See this link:-

http://animeshrivastava.blogspot.in/2017/07/generate-android-app-apk-on-shell-or.html

I am attaching the relevant parts :-

Generation of Android app at command prompt of Windows will be as follows:

1. Install Java .Only install version 6 standard edition as it is small size compatible with Android.
   Next install Android in folder.
   Run Android package manager and put Android API level 23 platform tools for version 6 of Android lollipop in directory

.This will have a file Android.jar containing all class files as a library jar for making a DALVIK-EXECUTABLE file run and execute as app on Android lollipop mobile.
Set path environment variable in  advance system settings of Windows. Include java-installation  in path variable.

2. Lets use shortcut mypro for my project. Mypkg means my package. Make directory folder
   Note that com.pkg is a package where dot or period separates com and pkg sub directories.
   In case your package doesn't have this dot or period, then during compilation no error but when you install in mobile, it will say invalid
3. Now we generate R class for res directory.

`enter code here`aapt p -S res -J ./com/pkg -I android.jar